# Octave: How do you plot a formula on an axis with a range of curves for a range of variable values?

Tags: formula, octave, array-formulas

How can I replicate this image, given this formula?
[image]
[image]

'Fx' is a range of values plotted on the X axis.

'm' is a static value (i.e. m=6)

'Q' is a variable that we need to input a range of values for so we can compare the curves.

Comment: What is the actual question? Are you having a problem with a specific part of the process? Or is the question literally "can someone code this graph for me"?

Comment: pls add more details

Comment: This question looks very similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497838/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803657/)